# Zend_Pdf Add text link to pdf page

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, zend-pdf

Is it possible to add anchor text(link) in Zend_PDF page?
I wasn't be able to find any information about this in Zend_Pdf online manual, or reading code, so I guess it is not possible.

If there is way, please suggest!

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Disable border:

```
...
$target = Zend_Pdf_Action_URI::create('http://example.com');
$annotation = Zend_Pdf_Annotation_Link::create(0,0,100,100,$target);
$annotation->getResource()->Border = new Zend_Pdf_Element_Array([
    new Zend_Pdf_Element_Numeric(0),
    new Zend_Pdf_Element_Numeric(0),
    new Zend_Pdf_Element_Numeric(0)
]);
$pdf->pages[0]->attachAnnotation($annotation);
...
```

Comment: Thanks, $annotation->getResource()->Border = new Zend_Pdf_Element_Array(); works for me :)

Answer (score 3):

The following code will create a blank page with a clickable area at the bottom left corner that contains a hyperlink:

```
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
$pdf->pages[0] = new Zend_Pdf_Page( Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4 );
$target = Zend_Pdf_Action_URI :: create( 'http://example.com' );
$annotation = Zend_Pdf_Annotation_Link :: create( 0, 0, 100, 100, $target );
$pdf->pages[0]->attachAnnotation( $annotation );
$pdf->save( 'test.pdf' );
```

The above snippet was tested with Zend Framework 1.10.7 but should work on all versions of Zend Framework from 1.9.7 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible - I tried to do something similar myself and unfortunately had to resort to [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) which isn't as good as Zend_Pdf.

I looked into implementing the link functionality in Zend_Pdf and the structure was too complicated for the amount of time I had to find a solution.

Comment: This is now possible with the release of Zend Framework 1.9 and the addition of support for annotations. Read more at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.interactive-features.html#zend.pdf.pages.interactive-features.annotations

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with the border issue and have resolved it with a rather simple hack:

```
echo str_replace('/Annot /Subtype /Link', '/Annot /Subtype /Link /Border[0 0 0]', $pdf->render());
```

This will make all anotations of type link to not have a border.